# Cisco Nexus 5548UP upgrade from 5.0.3 to 7.0.1

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, cisco-ios

We have one cisco `Nexus 5548UP` L2 switch running very old software `5.0.3` version but recently i got `7.0.1` software from someone else (we don't have SmartNet on this switch).

is it safe to upgrade from 5.0.3 to 7.0.1? I was trying to find prerequisite but i didn't find any so wonder if some already did in past please share your experience.

## UPDATE

after upgrade from 5.0.3 to 5.2.1 (for safety) look like my fan speed bump up from 50% to 60%. here is the `show env` output

```
`switch# show environment


Fan:
------------------------------------------------------
Fan             Model                Hw         Status
------------------------------------------------------
Chassis-1       N5548P-FAN           --         ok
Chassis-2       N5548P-FAN           --         ok
PS-1            N55-PAC-750W         --         failure
PS-2            N55-PAC-750W         --         ok


Temperature
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Module   Sensor     MajorThresh   MinorThres   CurTemp     Status
                    (Celsius)     (Celsius)    (Celsius)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1        Outlet     60            50           39          ok
```

`

fan details

```
switch# sh environment fan detail


Fan:
---------------------------------------------------
Module  Fan  Airflow        Speed(%)  Speed(RPM)
             Direction
---------------------------------------------------
1       1    Front-to-Back  60        15211
1       2    Front-to-Back  60        11816
1       3    Front-to-Back  60        15211
1       4    Front-to-Back  60        11663
2       1    Front-to-Back  60        15517
2       2    Front-to-Back  60        11842
2       3    Front-to-Back  60        15929
2       4    Front-to-Back  60        11842


Power Supply:
-----------------------------------
Module  Airflow        Configured
        Direction      Speed (%)
-----------------------------------
1       Unknown        60
2       Front-to-Back  60
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Before proceeding with any upgrade, please ensure you have both the kickstart and the system image file. The kickstart file will set all the variables for you, and the system will check for this on reload.

NOTE: The kickstart file needs to match the system image file version. Please do not try to proceed with upgrading without both of these files.

The quickest way to determine if you are able to upgrade this device is by issuing the show install command from the 5548:

show install all impact kickstart bootflash:

Example Output:

```
switch-1# show install all impact kickstart bootflash:n5000-uk9-kickstart.4.2.1.N1.1.bin
system bootflash:n5000-uk9.4.2.1.N1.1.bin
Verifying image bootflash:/n5000-uk9-kickstart.4.2.1.N1.1.bin for boot variable 
"kickstart".
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Verifying image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.4.2.1.N1.1.bin for boot variable "system".
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Verifying image type.
[###########         ]  50%
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Extracting "system" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.4.2.1.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Extracting "kickstart" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9-kickstart.4.2.1.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Extracting "bios" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.4.2.1.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Extracting "fex" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.4.2.1.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Notifying services about system upgrade.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS
Compatibility check is done:
Module  bootable          Impact  Install-type  Reason
------  --------  --------------  ------------  ------
  1       yes      disruptive         reset  Reset due to single supervisor
100       yes      disruptive         reset  Reset due to single supervisor
```

Images will be upgraded according to following table:
 Module       Image         Running-Version             New-Version  Upg-Required

---

```
  1      system             4.1(3)N1(1)             4.2(1)N1(1)           yes
  1   kickstart             4.1(3)N1(1)             4.2(1)N1(1)           yes
  1        bios        v1.3.0(09/08/09)                                    no
100         fex             4.1(3)N1(1)             4.2(1)N1(1)           yes
```

Please also refer to the official documentation for upgrading from that version:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/upgrade/503_N1_1/n5k_upgrade_downgrade_503.html?referring_site=RE&pos=1&page=http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/upgrade/513_N1_1/n5k_upgrade_downgrade_513.html

Comment: I have upgrade from 5.0.3 to 5.2.1 version for safety but look like my FAN running on max speed. what is the standard RPM speed for this switch? my fan running on `60%` speed `1       1    Front-to-Back  60        15517`

Comment: You should see a log entry for this, but the normal thresholds are between 7950 RPM and 12500, however if the environment is warmer or the switch is under high load that could be completely normal. If this is only intermittent I wouldn't worry to much. A show environment should be a tell to any potential issues.

Comment: Before upgrade speed was `50%` but now its `60%`, we are not in production its sitting in the LAB without any traffic

Comment: If environmentally there are no issues, and the temperature is not high in the room I would troubleshoot the hardware, there are many forums for users of this device of things to look at. If that yields nothing, I would open an RMA with Cisco.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Release Notes usually tells you about supported upgrade paths.  In your case, you don't have a choice.  Basically - try it.  Follow the directions in the [Cisco Nexus 5000 Series NX-OS Software Upgrade and Downgrade Guide, Release 5.0](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/upgrade/503_N1_1/n5k_upgrade_downgrade_503.html)

Also might look at the following.

[Cisco Nexus 5500 Series Release Notes, Cisco NX-OS Release 7.x](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/release/notes/7x/Nexus5500_Release_Notes_7x.html)  09/Jun/2016

[Cisco Nexus 5500 Series Release Notes, Cisco NX-OS Release 6.02](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/release/notes/6_02/Nexus5500_Release_Notes_6_02.html)  01/Jul/2014

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean say i should give it a try from `5.0.3 to 7.0.1` how should i configure boot variable so if 7.0.1 fail then it boot from 5.0.3?

Comment: switch(config)# boot system bootflash:n5000.bin    
 switch(config)# boot kickstart bootflash:n5000-kickstart.bin